# My DSLR takes photographs with black strip on top

Tags: nikon, dslr, troubleshooting, sync-speed

[image]

My DSLR is having an issue. What's the cause of this black thing on taking pictures? What solution probably can I do? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using flash? What is your shutter time?

Comment: I'm voting to close the question as too unclear

Comment: Why are you posting a photo of your camera instead of the actual photo with the problem? Is this only visible on the cameras lcd screen?

Answer (score 2):

It is a failing shutter.

[image: http://digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/shutteranimation2.gif]

If one of the curtains (or the mirror which blocks the light too) is moving badly you will get this problem (unless you are using flash of course which does not seem to be the case).

Unless you want to take a risk of replacing the shutter yourself take it to the service. In the best case it would only require cleaning the shutter but do not count on it.

You can verify that using live view: if the image is fine, it must be a problem with shutter.

Comment: It could also be using a Tv shorter than X-sync with a flash. The shutter could be perfectly fine.

Comment: I agree it's probably a failing shutter. 

But your animation is very wrong. 

(The curtains move in the same direction. Your mechanical arrangement has no way to generate a shutter speed faster than the sync speed.)

And yeah, you could be busting X-Sync, but cameras mostly make that impossible with flashes built for that system.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the curtains *are* moving in the same direction during the exposure portion of that animation.  They just happen to both be fully open at the same time, which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: @RogerKrueger the curtains are moving in the same direction right before and right after exposure. This is not even my animation.

Comment: @MichaelClark of course it could be sync issue and that's why I mentioned it. However after years of photography I can clearly see that there is no popup flash used for taking the OP photograph (deep shadows in front of objects) and it is not bounced flash either (check out reflections on the sofa which tell that the most powerful source of light is not on the camera at all). Those who downvoted do not get it.

Comment: "Deep shadows in front of objects." Really? Where? The light in the photo on the camera's LCD screen is consistent with a shoe mounted flash bounced straight off the ceiling which could account for both the shadows *under* certain items and the glare on the couch.

Comment: @MichaelClark there is a thing lying on the armrest which casts a shadow underneath which would be lit with pop-up flash. There is a tilted shadow in the bottom left corner which could not be made with a ceiling-bounced flash (which is only way there would be those shadows around wrinkles of the sofa).

Comment: @RogerKrueger The position of curtains is correct. If they would be both one-side, one of the is useless and one side of the image would be overexposed and the second one (the one where they would be mounted) would be underexposed. Old SLRS (I played with Petri) have the sequence: Prepare (Open rear curtain and close front); Lift the mirror and open the front curtain from one side (start exposure, curtain moves leftways); Shut the rear curtain (exposure ends, curtain moves leftways) and release the mirror.

Comment: Hey. Im not an expert photographer or so but Im sure that the black line on top is consistent whenever I tried to took pictures (different angle, different exposure, etc) I tried to change the lens but it turns out that it's not the problem.

Comment: @ShielaMaeBautista the point stands: if you were not using flash this is a definite sign of shuter damage.